# What is the best practice to save access token in react-native app with redux?

Tags: firebase, react-native, redux

What is the best practice to save access token in react-native app with redux?

In Redux, I used to save the whole credential, including some user information to the state:

```
//Actions
export const successfulLogin = (firebaseAuth) => ({
    type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL',
    firebaseAuth
});

//Reducer
const authentication = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL':
            return {
                ...state,
                firebaseAuth: action.firebaseAuth
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
export default authentication
```

After that, I found a new module `redux-persist`, which helps me to save the state to device storage, `localStorage`. However, everything in the store will be saved. Is it a good practice to save access token with redux-persist?

If not, what should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're describing works, but it's a bit overkill to save the entire store if you only need one access token. Therefore I'd say it's best practice to accomplish exactly what you need with a bit of code.

As an alternative to using `redux-persist` you can just do this side effect handling yourself:

1. Read the access token from localStorage when redux' `createStore` is called and pass it into the preloaded state. Or..
2. Dispatch an action like `SET_ACCESS_TOKEN` to add the token to the redux store at a later point.
3. To save the token right after successful login, you can trigger a side effect (calling a module that is responsible for writing something to localStorage) in the respective async action creator.

That's it, no additional modules necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since this question was asked but with redux-persist you don't need to save the entire store. You can provide keys that you want to store and it will ignore keys that you have not specified.